# Fitting into GridSearchCV

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

What X,y I should fit into GridSearchCV? That I have used to train model or to test model?
As I found out that using wrong one, resulted in bad accuracy score for the model ;C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always perform `GridSearchCV` on your train set, thus `X_train` and `y_train`.